# Can I see Symbol Load Table of Rcpp on R?

Tags: r

Sometime I got a message on R

```
> .Call("blablabla")
Error in .Call("blablabla") : C symbol name "blablabla" not in load table
```

Can I check what is loaded on the table of C symbol name?
Is there R command showing the C symbol name on load table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if the package registers them. Check ?getDLLRegisteredRoutines.