# How can I register C symbols in the R load table?

Tags: c++, r

**This does not work**

There is various manuals on how to include C and C++ code in R *without Rcpp*. Following the first example [in this manual](https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-ways-to-call-cc-from-r/) and writing a c++ function

```
void double_me(int* x) {
    // Doubles the value at the memory location pointed to by x
    *x = *x + *x;
}
```

into a file `doubler.cpp` and compiling

```
R CMD SHLIB doubler.cpp
```

works fine. The process results in additional files `doubler.o` and `doubler.so`. The shared object can be loaded from R, but does not register the symbol `double_me` it is supposed to expose:

```
> dyn.load("doubler.so")
> getLoadedDLLs()
                                                                    Filename
base                                                                    base
methods                           /usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so
utils                                 /usr/lib/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so
grDevices                     /usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so
graphics                        /usr/lib/R/library/graphics/libs/graphics.so
stats                                 /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
doubler                                   /home/<user>/<path>/src/doubler.so
tools                                 /usr/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so
                   Dynamic.Lookup
base                        FALSE
methods                     FALSE
utils                       FALSE
grDevices                   FALSE
graphics                    FALSE
stats                       FALSE
doubler                      TRUE
tools                       FALSE

>  getDLLRegisteredRoutines("doubler")
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Consequently

```
> .C("double_me", as.integer(1))
Error in .C("double_me") : C symbol name "double_me" not in load table
```

And evidently, there is something missing - presumably the registration of the symbol (the name of the function) in the load table.

**This works, but it is hard to understand, how**

According to [this manual](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Interfacing%20C++%20code) we are supposed to apply

```
extern "C" {

}
```

to third functions in another file. In [the manual](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Interfacing%20C++%20code), this is a function in `X_main.o`, compiled alongside the loaded library (`X.so`) that apparently gets registered in the load table without ever being explicitly loaded. And it can then be called with `.C("X_main")` nevertheless.

I am not sure how exactly this works or how it could be applied to the [first example with the trivial double_me function](https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-ways-to-call-cc-from-r/).

**Related questions**

There are many questions that are likely related to this on Stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, none of them has a well-explained answer. Examples are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29443730), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24853377), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9740247), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39354959).

Comment: This is a package right? Have you done `useDynLib` in your `NAMESPACE`? See also this specific section of R-exts: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you; this may be a promising approach. However, I do not know how to control the NAMESPACE since I am not writing a package but loading a `.so` from the R interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ allows for overloading, where you can have the same function with different arguments. In order to achieve this, they have to have different names in the compiled file. So when you declare `void double_me(int* x)` as a C++ function, it'll actually be compiled down to something with a horrible suffix on the name. See for example https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html for details. If you specify C linkage, name mangling doesn't occur, and it gets output with a fairly normal name.

Back to your question, the function you want to call from R should probably have C linkage. That's it. You're getting confused about needing third functions, etc. Just mark `double_me` as extern "C" and you'll be all good.

You probably need to register the function with R, even so.....

Comment: You are right, marking as `extern "C"` and recompiling is sufficient. I am not sure why I missed this. Weirdly, however, `getDLLRegisteredRoutines("doubler")` still shows nothing although the routine is now accessible through `.C()`.

Comment: I assume that `getDLLRegisteredRoutines` lists you out the symbols registered by the package with R. By just marking it as `extern "C"` you've created a symbol with a specific name, which you can then directly call. The are probably hundreds of thousands of symbols, and R doesn't know that specific symbol is a callable function, until it actually tries to call it using `.C(...)`. You need an init function that registers the function with R.